How come a blue-maned lynel dropped a normal Lynel Crusher?
I was playing Botw Normal mode today, and I was upset because ages ago I lost access to Lynel Spears and Crushers, and I wanted to complete my hyrule compendium by hand but then today I was getting the blue maned lynels weapons so I wouldn't miss those but the first one I defeated was the one just below where you get Ganon Horse, it was a spear Lynel but when I picked up the loot it was a NORMAL Lynel Spear?!? How did this happen its meant to be permanently missable!!
Also in addition to that he dropped a MIGHTY LYNEL BOW not a NORMAL one?!?

also if this happens can i also get lynel crusher? then i have all the missable items

Why do you think these weapons are missable in the first place?

do you mean why or why they make them missable? if 1 then cus of hidden xp system more details of that on zelda fandom, if 2 then idk?

i need Lynel Crusher...

In Breath of the Wild, as you mention, enemies "level up" to tougher versions based on a hidden experience system. Enemy equipment also levels up, but not at the same rate - thus, there are periods where an enemy might change to a tougher version before its weapon does, or where the weapon might change to a stronger version before the enemy does. To be specific, in the case of Lynels and their weapons:
A Lynel Bow changes to a Mighty Lynel Bow after 1416.67 points.
A Lynel Crusher changes to a Mighty Lynel Crusher after 2722.22 points.
A regular Lynel changes to a Blue-Maned Lynel after 2785.71 points.
A Lynel Spear changes to a Mighty Lynel Spear after 3000 points.
Thus, if you currently have between 2785.71 and 3000 hidden experience points, you are able to encounter Blue-Maned Lynels, Mighty Lynel Bows, Mighty Lynel Crushers but regular Lynel Spears. Unfortunately, you will be unable to get the regular Lynel Crushers, as they "evolve" earlier than the Spears.
Info taken from this Google Doc: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRSlyOD7FLAn1TUBn64Pu8Pld-WOfgcVByuywHMWvBTEV0j8potD1wkBs-MJJXf-gvEkpfItUCMqMk6/pubhtml#

sigh I was hoping to get the Lynel crushed but no I don't care...
